# php exec on windows server

Tags: php, windows

I have installed the php on my windows server and configured it to run with iis

From the folder inetpub/wwwroot/  I am executing a php file which contains the following code

```
<?php
exec("md example_dir",$output,$error);
print_r($output);
print_r($error);
?>
```

its a simple make directory command. but it gives me output as

Array ( ) 1

I have googled a lot, and found that 1 means some general permission problem.

I even gave cmd.exe the IIUSR permission.
But still not working..can anyone help ?

Comment: The missing permission is most likely on the folder, not the executable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case use (.) to combine example  `exec("mkdir ".$dir);`   $dir contain dir name

```
                       OR

    <?php
    mkdir("example_dir");
    ?>
```

Use this command mkdir can be used directly like in cmd.

You can provide read write permission also

```
mkdir('mydir', 0777);
```